# How to close child forms running in their own threads when parent form closes? (non MDI)

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, parent-child

I have an app where multiple child forms are spawned from a parent form, using a single child form definintion (i.e. frmParent spawns multiple instances of frmChild).

Each child runs in it's own thread - I want to be able to interact with each child independently (and I don't like MDI).

So - if the parent form is closed, how do I instruct the child forms to close themselves?

```
        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(delegate ()
        {
            using (Child child = new Child())
            {
                child.MyName = "1";
                child.ShowDialog();
            }
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(delegate ()
        {
            using (Child child = new Child())
            {
                child.MyName = "2";
                child.ShowDialog();
            }
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
    }
```

Comment: All UI components should be running on just one thread: the main (UI) thread.  That's the rule.

Comment: Are you sure they're in their own threads? Usually there's only one UI thread. How are you showing them?

Comment: So how do you get multiple forms running independently if you don't want to use MDI if you don't use multiple threads?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Code added to question

Comment: Just use `child.Show()`. You don't need/should not use another thread.

Comment: @RezaAghaei child form disappears if I use child.Show() - and can I spawn multiple instances of child?

Comment: Without using another thread in above click event handlers, just write: `new Child().Show();`

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yep, thanks.

Comment: It's better to edit the answer and put a conclusion based on comments, like *As a concolution based on comments, all UI components should be running on just one thread: the main (UI) thread. That's the rule. You don't need/should not use another thread. So without using another thread in click event handlers, just write: `new Child().Show();`*. It's a more a complete and useful answer. You will have my vote.

Comment: Done as suggested  :)

Comment: Good job! Also read the linked post about [Do I need to Dispose a Form after the Form got Closed?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39501121/3110834).

Answer (score 2):

As a conclusion based on comments, all UI components should be running on just one thread: the main (UI) thread. That's the rule. You don't need/should not use another thread. So without using another thread in click event handlers, just write: new Child().Show();

Comment: Do not write `new Child().Show()` as `Child` is disposable. It's a memory leak this way.

Comment: So what IS the solution then?

Comment: @Enigmativity That doesn't leak.  The form will be added to the Application.OpenForms collection and will be disposed of by the user or by the program when the user closes the main form.

Comment: [Do I need to Dispose a Form after the Form got Closed?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39501121/3110834)

Comment: @Enigmativity When you show a form using `Show` method you don't need to (and you can't) call Dispose. The form will be disposed itself after got closed.