# Windows Forms: wait until another form closes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a situation in which `formA` needs to update some data, but only after `formB` has closed. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
private void newProjectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewProjectForm newProjectForm = new NewProjectForm();
    newProjectForm.Show();

    //wait for newProjectForm to close...

    DataTable dt = Util.ToDataTable(ProjectParticipantTable.GetUserProjectsDetails(Util.currentUserId));
    userProjectsDGV.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `ShowDialog`?

Comment: I'm guessing `formB` isn't modal? Seems to be too obvious a solution.

Comment: As Reza suggest change the `Show()` to `ShowDialog();` You will not be able to do anything with your other currently open forms until `newProjectForm` is closed.

Comment: That was embarrassingly simple. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to make use of `ShowDialog()` method, and managhe the `DialogResult` property. For doing that, you have to set the `DialogResult` set on some part of NewProjectForm, that can be done setting the property in a button, or simply setting it by code. That will fire the DialogResult to your parent form and close the Form

You can do that this way:

```
using(NewProjectForm newProjectForm = new NewProjectForm())
{
   if(newProjectForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
       DataTable dt = Util.ToDataTable(ProjectParticipantTable.GetUserProjectsDetails(Util.currentUserId));
       userProjectsDGV.DataSource = dt;
   }
}
```

Comment: [Do I need to Dispose a Form after the Form got Closed?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39501121/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei you ´ve got it. I updated my answer for keeping up with good practices

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the modal showdialog mode you can also use this approach.

```
private void newProjectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewProjectForm newProjectForm = new NewProjectForm();
    newProjectForm.FormClosed += NewProjectForm_FormClosed;
    newProjectForm.Show();
}

private void NewProjectForm_FormClosed(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    ////will run when new form is closed

    DataTable dt = Util.ToDataTable(ProjectParticipantTable.GetUserProjectsDetails(Util.currentUserId));
    userProjectsDGV.DataSource = dt;
}
```

If you want only a singleton then make the newProjectForm variable a static singleton.