# How to ensure garbage collection when user closes a non-modal window?

Tags: c#, winforms, garbage-collection, non-modal

In my C# Winforms App, I have the following (minimal code shown)

Form1 is the main app that the user uses to do stuff. Form2 shows a help file that explains how to use the features on Form1 to do stuff. I want the user to be able to display (modeless) and close the help file at will so long as Form1 is visible.

I also worry about the memory leak that may occur as the user opens and closes Form2. So, when the user closes Form2, it raises an event that Form1 subscribes to. When the Form1 event method is invoked, is calls Dispose() on Form2, sets the Form2 object to null and calls the garbage collector.

Will this remove the chance for a memory leak caused by the user opening and closing Form2? Is it overkill? Is there a better way of ensuring garbage collection at the point in time that Form2 is closed? ***I don't want to rely on Windows doing it later when it decides to***

**UPDATE**

Jimi pointed out that I don't need a custom event handler for the Form2 Closed event. He's right. In my Form1 class, I'm now using the standard FormClosedEventHandler for my Form2. The code itself, however remains pretty much the same. However, when I remove the call to GC.Collect(), I'm seeing evidence of a memory leak using Task Manager.

Here's my data:

```
Run #1. Form2_FormClosed method has:
------------------------------------
f_HelpForm.Dispose();
f_HelpForm = null;
GC.Collect();

Start App
Task Manager Memory for app: 6.7 MB
Open and Close Form2 20 times
Task Manager Memory for app: 8.2 MB

Run #2. Form2_FormClosed method has:
------------------------------------
f_HelpForm.Dispose();
f_HelpForm = null;
//GC.Collect();

Start App
Task Manager Memory for app: 6.9 MB
Open and Close Form2 20 times
Task Manager Memory for app: 18.9 MB

Run #3. Form2_FormClosed method has:
------------------------------------
//f_HelpForm.Dispose();
f_HelpForm = null;
//GC.Collect();

Start App
Task Manager Memory for app: 6.9 MB
Open and Close Form2 20 times
Task Manager Memory for app: 18.1 M
```

Without the call to GC.Collect(), and with or without the call to Dispose(), the footprint grows 100% bigger as compared to the code that includes the call to GC.collect().

I hear what you guys are saying, but .......... I think I'll leave my code in its "Run #1" configuration

**The code**

*Note: I acknowledge that setting form2 = null has a direct influence on behind-the-scenes garbage collection. However, my purpose in setting form2 = null is to provide a signal to the `Form2Button_Click` method that it can use to decide whether or not to instantiate a Form2 object*

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 form2;
    
    public Form1()
    {
        form2 = null;
    }  

    private void Form2Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (form2 == null)
        {
            form2 = new ClsHelpForm(this);
            form2.Form2Closed += Form2_FormClosed;
        }

        form2.Select();
        form2.Show();
    }

    //When this user clicks the Help button on Form1, this method is invoked
    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2.Form2Closed -= Form2_FormClosed;
        form2.Dispose();
        form2 = null;
        GC.Collect();
    }   
{

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler Form2Closed;

    public Form2()
    {
    }

    //When the user clicks the "X" button on Form2, this method is invoked
    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, Form2EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2Closed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont need `public event EventHandler Form2Closed;` at all, you can subscribe to the `FormClosed` event without it. Remove the handler in Form1 when the standard event is raised. That's all -- Did you notice that some memory is not reclaimed when Form2 is closed, using a profiler, e.g., the Diagnostic Tools? -- `GC.Collect();` has no purpose: it either can collect what's collectable or it cannot. If it can, it'll do it when needed.

Comment: Forcing GC will never fix "memory leaks" (which technically don't exist in pure C# safe code)... It is possibly you are talking about some sort of long-living references which again not going to be cleaned up by GC.

Comment: [Do I need to Dispose a Form after closing the Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501121/3110834)

Comment: @cj.burrow @Jimi: I agree I don't need my custom event handler. In my Form1 class, I'm now using the standard `FormClosedEventHandler` for my Form2. However, when I remove the call to `GC.Collect()`, I'm seeing evidence of a memory leak using Task Manager. I'll update my question with my findings ASAP

Comment: You shouldn't do profiling with Taskmanager. It may be helpful on the large scale in comparing resource usage against other process but thats it. If you suspect something like a leak use a real profiler like the Diagnostics Tools available in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Ralf I see you point, but I'm not doing "Profiling". I'm using Task Manager as a blunt instrument to see if the memory footprint of my app grows or not. My empirical observations indicate a 100% growth in memory footprint for my Run #2 and my Run #3 as compared to my Run #1. Are you saying this 100% growth would disappear if I observed it using a "real leak profiler" as opposed to task manager?

Comment: @RezaAghaei: Agreed. My Run #2 and my Run #3 indicate it doesn't matter (much) whether I call Dispose() or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A member instance of `Form2` doesn't take a lot of room on the heap and there seems to be little cause to create and destroy its Handle every time the user wants to show it.

[image: managed memory]

Why not just prevent the destruction of the `Form2` handle until app closes?

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(Form owner)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Owner = owner;
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    }
    protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
        if(Visible)
        {
            Location = new Point(
                Owner.Location.X + Owner.Width + 10,
                Owner.Location.Y);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
        if(e.CloseReason.Equals(CloseReason.UserClosing))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

When the form2 is cycled (by automation) 100 times, monitoring the process memory shows zero GCs and no direct correlation to the number of times shown.

[image: process memory]

Where:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 _form2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _form2 = new Form2(this);
        Disposed += (sender, e) => _form2.Dispose();
        buttonShowHelp.Click += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown.Value; i++)
            {
                _form2.Visible = true;
                await Task.Delay(500);
                _form2.Visible = false;
                await Task.Delay(500);
            }
            // But leave it open after cycling.
            _form2.Visible = true;
        };
    }
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the purpose of `Disposed += (sender, e) => _form2.Dispose();` ?  I'm asking because  Reza Aghaei's comment to my question points to a SO answer that indicates that a form displayed using .Show() (as is the case for my form2) does not require a call to Dispose()

Comment: Thx for the question! Reza Aghaei is correct that this is the _default_ behavior of `Show` (as opposed to `ShowDialog`) that the Handle will be destroyed when the form closes, allowing GC if the form goes out of scope or gets nulled out. The `Form2` code in my example makes a point of preventing this from happening, but it leaves us with the responsibility to make sure that handle gets disposed when the main app closes.

Comment: I suppose that in fact the line you mention is probably not strictly necessary, because when the `e.CloseReason` is _not_ `CloseReason.UserClosing` (like when the app is closing) the default behavior will be allowed. I think I include the explicit dispose somewhat reflexively, because leaving a hanging native HWnd _will prevent_ the app from shutting down. Which is maddening. So, cheap insurance, you know? Bottom line, probably could be eliminated just test and look for any funny app shutdown behavior.

Answer (score 2):

> I also worry about the memory leak that may occur as the user opens and closes Form2.

Why are you worried about a memory leak? Don't try to optimize when there's no evidence of a problem. As long as Form2 and all of its child objects actually clean up resources when Dispose is called, there should be no memory leak.

> Is there a better way of ensuring garbage collection at the point in time that Form2 is closed? I don't want to rely on Windows doing it later when it decides to

This seems like unnecessary paranoia. Just be sure Form2 cleans up in its Dispose method and let garbage collection occur naturally. Everything looks fine except remove the GC.Collect() call.

Comment: Not saying you're wrong based on conventional wisdom, but I can't explain my empirical observations. Please see my test data in my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

If you put trash in the kitchen garbage can, and 5 minutes later the trash is still there, it does NOT mean that the trash will be there forever. It just means that *the trash hasn't been emptied yet*. It will get emptied *eventually* once it gets full enough. A "leak" would be if you put your trash *on the floor*, in which case it would *not* get picked up when the trashcan gets full. (not a perfect analogy, since someone is (hopefully) going to pick it up at some point, but you get the idea)

Your observations probably show a 100% growth because there's no memory pressure to require a collection. A memory leak would only occur if that memory *never*  gets freed by the GC, which forcing a garbage collection would not fix. An example of a memory leak would be a reference to an unmanaged resource that is not release when the form is disposed (not closed).

Calling `GC.Collect` yourself is not going to fix memory leaks - it just cleans up memory *earlier* that the system needs to.

Comment: When I read your comment "A memory leak would only occur if that memory never gets freed by the GC" and "GC.Collect ....  just cleans up memory earlier" makes me realize I was misusing the term myself. I see what you and cj.Burrow are saying now. Thank-you for getting me right on what a memory leak is